# Qual a ordem de retorno dos atributos da função getelementbyid?

Tags: javascript

O site do w3cschools tem um exemplo da função [getelementbyid()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_node_attributes4). Acontece que em cada navegador esse exemplo tem um retorno diferente e eu não consigui encontrar uma resposta do pq disso. Alguém faz ideia do pq isso acontece?
o exemplo é esse:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="myImg" alt="Flower" src="klematis.jpg" width="150" height="113">

<p>Click the button to display each attribute's name and value of the image above.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myImg");
    var txt = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.attributes.length; i++) {
        txt = txt + x.attributes[i].name + " = " + x.attributes[i].value + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As respostas de cada browser são essas:

```
- Firefox 30.0:

    width = 150
    height = 113
    src = klematis.jpg
    alt = Flower
    id = myImg

 - Chrome 36.0.1985.125:

    id = myImg
    alt = Flower
    src = klematis.jpg
    width = 150
    height = 113

 - IE 11.0.9600.17207

    width = 150
    height = 113
    id = myImg
    alt = Flower
    src = klematis.jpg
```

Por exemplo, se eu quiser ter acesso ao atributo id no ff o índice vai ser 4, no chrome vai ser 0 e no IE vai ser 2.

Comment: A ordem é irrelevante nesse caso não acha? uma vez que você pode acessar os atributos do objeto associativamente pelo nome. Creio que as ordens diferentes se dão pelo simples fato de como cada navegador ordena os atributos na memória.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Todo elemento do DOM, acessível via JavaScript (seja retornado por `document.getElementById` seja por outros meios) possuem [uma propriedade `attribute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-84CF096) que é [do tipo `NamedNodeMap`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1780488922). Traduzindo livremente da especificação linkada acima (ênfase minha):

> Objetos implementando a interface NamedNodeMap são usados para representar coleções de Nodes que podem ser acessados via nome. Note que o NamedNodeMap não herda de NodeList; NamedNodeMaps **não são mantidos em nenhuma ordem em particular**. Objetos contidos em um objeto implementando NamedNodeMap **podem também ser acessados por um índice ordinal**, mas isso é simplesmente para permitir uma enumeração conveniente dos conteúdos de um NamedNodeMap, o que **não implica que o DOM especifica uma ordem** a esses Nodes.

Ou seja, como a especificação não impõe nenhuma ordem, cada browser é livre para implementar do jeito que quiser (inclusive mudar a ordem dinamicamente durante o ciclo de vida da página). Não se deve portanto depender de uma ordem específica ao se fazer uso dessa API.

Como [apontado por Cahe nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25948/qual-a-ordem-de-retorno-dos-atributos-da-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-getelementbyid#comment48150_25948), a melhor maneira de se acessar esses atributos é por nome, e não por índice. Exemplo:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myImg");
var txt = "";
txt = txt + "id = "     + x.attributes.getNamedItem("id").value + "<br>";
txt = txt + "src = "    + x.attributes.getNamedItem("src").value + "<br>";
txt = txt + "width = "  + x.attributes.getNamedItem("width").value + "<br>";
txt = txt + "height = " + x.attributes.getNamedItem("height").value + "<br>";
txt = txt + "alt = "    + x.attributes.getNamedItem("src").value + "<br>";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
```

Ou simplesmente (cuidado com colisões de nomes):

```
var x = document.getElementById("myImg");
var txt = "";
txt = txt + "id = "     + x.attributes.id.value + "<br>";
txt = txt + "src = "    + x.attributes.src.value + "<br>";
txt = txt + "width = "  + x.attributes.width.value + "<br>";
txt = txt + "height = " + x.attributes.height.value + "<br>";
txt = txt + "alt = "    + x.attributes.src.value + "<br>";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
```